# Angular's http.get is not importing my json file - it is giving a parse error

Tags: json, angularjs, http

I've got some JSON that looks like this:

```
[
     {
         _id: ObjectId("544809736654daf1ea897ca"),
         project: "demo",
         tools: ['ajax', 'javascript', 'html'],
     },
     {
         _id: ObjectId("322148965654daf1ea81ca"),
         project: "trial",
         tools: ['haskell'],
     }
]
```

I've saved it in a file called `items`.

I'm trying to import it to my Angular project with this code:

```
app.service("getItemsService", 
    function($http, $q){
        return {
            getItems: function getItems(){
                return $http.get('data/_items').success(function(data){
                    return data;
                }); 
            }
        }
    }
);
```

but when I do, I get an error saying:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token _
    at Object.parse (native)
```

I've tried everything I can think of to fix this - i.e. I've named the file `items.json`, I changed `_id` to `id`, I've tried adding `{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` to `get()` function as a parameter to indicate its JSON.
Nothing is working! Any tips?

Comment: what does the server side look like?  `'data/_items'` as the get method looks a little goofy to me.  What are you doing with the returned data, where is the error happening?

Comment: Is your issue fixed ? Are you able to accept one of the two proposed answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try your JSON in a linter in that kind of problem like http://jsonlint.com/
It would have tell you

```
Parse error on line 2:
[    {        _id: ObjectId("54480
--------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

That is a little less cryptic : it tells you that _id is not a String => you'r missing the "

After that it will tell you that :

```
Parse error on line 3:
...   {        "_id": ObjectId("5448097366
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

ObjectId is not valid for JSON, you have to find somehting else, like only the id, or all in a String :

```
[
{
    "_id": "544809736654daf1ea897ca",
    "project": "demo",
    "tools": [
        'ajax',
        'javascript',
        'html'
    ],

},
{
    "_id": "322148965654daf1ea81ca",
    "project": "trial",
    "tools": [
        'haskell'
    ],

}
]
```

But hey, it's not finish :

```
Parse error on line 5:
...ols": [            'ajax',            
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', ']'
```

Well yeah, ' is not valid, some parser actualy fail on single quote.

```
[
{
    "_id": "544809736654daf1ea897ca",
    "project": "demo",
    "tools": [
        "ajax",
        "javascript",
        "html"
    ],

},
{
    "_id": "322148965654daf1ea81ca",
    "project": "trial",
    "tools": [
        "haskell"
    ],

}
]
```

Still not there :

```
Parse error on line 9:
...    ],            },    {        "_i
---------------------^
Expecting 'STRING'
```

it seems that there is a trouble around line 9, and if you look closely you will see a , with nothing behind, let's remove the useless ,

```
[
{
    "_id": "544809736654daf1ea897ca",
    "project": "demo",
    "tools": [
        "ajax",
        "javascript",
        "html"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "322148965654daf1ea81ca",
    "project": "trial",
    "tools": [
        "haskell"
    ]
}
]
```

And here it is !

[image]

Comment: Wow. Ok, that's interesting. So is there any way to import JSON as a Javascript object?

Comment: JSON IS a javascript object, but it has to be valid ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your angular service seems good. It is your "JSON" content file that is not formated as a regular JSON string:

1. properties as to be strings double quoted
2. values as to be strings double quoted or object `{}` or arrays `[]`
3. functions couldn't be used in json strings (your ObjectId() function)
4. Last elements in arrays can't finish by a comma as the previous elements

Try this instead :

```
[
     {
         "_id": "544809736654daf1ea897ca",
         "project": "demo",
         "tools": ["ajax", "javascript", "html"]
     },
     {
         "_id": "322148965654daf1ea81ca",
         "project": "trial",
         "tools": ["haskell"]
     }
]
```

Comment: You can use [this online json parser tool](http://json.parser.online.fr) to check your (small) JSON strings or JSON content files.